# Installing Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to install Python 3.6.4 on my new laptop with Windows 8, but when I launch the IDLE, it shows me an error :

```
The program can't start because api-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to google the error message?

Comment: This should be closed as a mega-duplicate.  Searching SO for `api-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll` returns 130 hits, many not related to Python.  I did not vote to close only because to do so requires picking just one ;-).  Note: the program that could not start is Python, not IDLE,

Answer (score 1):

After googling your error message, it seems that you need to update your C Runtime libraries.

Official instructions and downloads from Microsoft's site are [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)